# Console window no longer appearing correctly

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.5

My console window is not longer baked into Eclipse. It appears as a seperate window which hovers over my any open project file windows. I don't know what I did to cause this. I've tried re-starting Eclispe, opening and closing the console view.

Screenshot attached

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution, right click on console window and un check "Detached" option.